# laravel 5.8.* installation failed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I run a clean install laravel 5.8 get an error

Laravel version 5.7 is installed without problems. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Generating optimized autoload files

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(790): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array)
#3 /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#4 /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1225): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
#5 /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(417): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('config')
#6 /h in /home/projects/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 790

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

**Updated** my
.env file
This file is created during installation

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Delete `bootstrap/cache/config.php` and run `php artisan clear:config` first.

Comment: bootstrap/cache/config.php -  No such file.
php artisan clear:config - Getting an error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in ....

Comment: Can you post your `.env` file's content?

Comment: Added to the main post

Comment: did you try `php artisan clear` and 
`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Looks like you have not set `APP_KEY` in '.env'. Please use `php artisan key:generate` to generate `APP_KEY` first then try your command.

Comment: It seems your project cannot find a class. Does this file exist in your project: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php` ?
If so, try `composer dump-autoload`. If not, you might need to try `composer install`

Comment: I use the command to install composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
After that, I get the error that is described above, all php artisan commands give the same error

Comment: Try to reinstall laravel at some other place. And please don't stop the process before it installs fully. Or you can try `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

I do not see **APP_KEY** in your `.env` file.

At the command line, issue the following Artisan command to generate a key:

```
php artisan key: generate
```

This will generate a random key for `APP_KEY`, After completion of `.env` edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:`php artisan config:cache`

---

If you faced a problem because the **vendor folder** then follows these steps:

```
composer update --no-scripts 
composer update
```

- **--no-scripts**: Skips execution of scripts defined in `composer.json`
- **composer update**: This will check for newer versions of the libraries you required in your project. If a newer version is found and it's compatible with the version constraint defined in the `composer.json` file, it will replace the previous version installed. The `composer.lock` file will be updated to reflect these changes.

These two commands, we will Recreate the **vendor folder** in our project

Comment: I use the command to install composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
After that, I get the error that is described above, all php artisan commands give the same error

Comment: please check have you **vendor folder** in your project

Comment: Yes I have a folder vendor.
As I wrote earlier this error only when installing laravel 5.8
Version 5.7 is installed without problems.

Comment: You have to face the problem because it is also possible during the installation time that you have not completed the process properly, try to **reinstall laravel**

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall `laravel`. Please delete your `vendor` directory or rename it and then run `composer install`.